# Check battery level of connected bluetooth device on linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

How can I check the battery level of a connected bluetooth device? The device shows the battery level on Android so I'm assuming the device supports the [GATT-based Battery Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml). However, by entering "menu gatt" in bluetoothctl and then listing the GATT attributes of the device with "list-attributes [dev]", nothing shows up.

A [similar question was posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058357/how-to-check-battery-level-of-a-bluetooth-paired-remote) but the OP seems to have found a solution that doesn't work for me. When I run "info [dev]" in bluetoothctl I don't see the UUID for Battery Service.

I would prefer a solution that runs on the command line and is distro-agnostic.

Please let me know if this question should be posted on SuperUser instead.

Comment: What type of device are we talking about? Battery level can be reported via many different profiles over Bluetooth, not only via LE GATT service... can you use a BLE explore app or the like to browse the GATT services and confirm what it actually supports?

Comment: Can you recommend a BLE explore app? Is there a way to know what type of device is connected from a command line tool (eg bluetoothctl)?

Comment: I check the contents of `/sys/class/power_supply`, as explained in [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53880/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-battery-percentage-of-apple-wireless-peripherals).

Comment: @DamianNadales my `/sys/class/power_supply` only contains `AC` and `BAT0`.

Comment: Oh. Then I don't know :/

Comment: @Ricardo when you say "nothing shows up with `list-attributes [dev]`". Do you mean there is not GATT attribute at all? If there are attributes, could you share them?

Comment: @OlivierM, yes, I mean no GATT attribute at all.

Comment: Can you tell which device it is? It might not support BLE but only legacy bluetooth...

Comment: @OlivierM, the device is the [Mpow 059 Bluetooth Headphones](https://www.xmpow.com/mpow-m3-over-ear-bluetooth-headphone.html)

Comment: I suspect your device does not use BLE for the connection (even if it supports it). Can you start `bluetoothd` in debug mode: `systemctl stop bluetooth.service && sudo ./src/bluetoothd -d -n`

Comment: @OlivierM, what should I look for? A few of the first and last output lines can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/rhz/47ae7e325e2fad8fac5af6cd6ea7b6ac).

Comment: It looks your bluetooth device is only exposed through A2DP (Advanced Audio
Distribution Profile). The battery information might be available through this Bluetooth profile.

Comment: How does one access the A2DP bluetooth profile? How do I check whether the battery information is available through that profile?

Comment: @Ricardo Looking at this page https://github.com/wangrunz/BluetoothMonitor#battery-level-for-bluetooth-headsets-support-handsfree-profile it looks like you need to send some AT commands. While it could be feasible in command line using my command https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008142/6267288 - it might be more convenient to do it using a programming language.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierM! I understand vaguely what has to be done. Concretely I don't know what to do. It seems the author of that app is having issues as well. I hope someone will write an answer to the question with concrete commands to run to obtain the battery level of a bluetooth device like mine.

Comment: Hey @OlivierM, do you know how you could use `dbus-send` to send those AT commands to the device?

Comment: @Ricardo for BLE device, I am not sure you can do it using `dbus`.

Comment: Why would that be so @OlivierM? Are BLE devices not exposed through the dbus interface?

Comment: It is the GATT layer that is exposed through `dbus`. Not the ATT layer.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for the clarification @OlivierM. What did you have in mind in your [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment99324302_49078659) when you said that it could be feasible to send some AT commands using your command in stackoverflow.com/a/55008142/6267288?

Comment: Same question on  Ask Ubuntu: [Check Bluetooth headphones battery status in Linux - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117563/check-bluetooth-headphones-battery-status-in-linux)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This might be a bit late to the party but for me this Python project has worked fine:

https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level

I only had to change the port in line 57 to 3 for my no-name X5 headset. If it hangs or errors with "connection refused" try a different port.

The Python program uses AT commands via RFCOMM and should work while Pulseaudio is using the A2DP sink (mine reconnects). Python 3 is needed as 2 doesn't have BT-Serial sockets. Windows will probably not work as it lacks bluez. It basically does the same thing as the Pulseaudio hack here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56390625/920122

If you want to look at the commands as they are exchanged, try my debug fork: https://github.com/clst/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level

Comment: Hey @clst, thanks for the answer! It looks promising! You mean the port in line 56 of the original code and 58 in your fork? The one that says `s.connect((BT_ADDRESS, 3))`? I tried with all the numbers from 1 to 11 and didn't work. Should I continue trying with more port numbers? Do you know what's the range of numbers in which the port may lie?

Comment: I tried again, this time after disconnecting from the device with `bluetoothctl`. **It works!!** `:)` I'm using your fork and port number 3. The only caveat is that I can't use this while listening to music, as I have to disconnect from the device to use the python script.

Comment: Yeah, those port numbers are device specific and there is no common practice so you would have to try them. If the RFCOMM works while the device is doing other things (like A2DP) is also device specific. Until someone codes a robust auto detect system this is the best we have `:)`

Comment: @clst do you know if this approach can be used to get battery level of apple watch and apple pencil over bluetooth as well?

Comment: I have no idea. Since this is an Apple proprietary protocol it might. I have no Apple hardware so I can't be much help.

Answer (score 40):

For me running this in terminal worked:

```
upower --dump
```

Comment: Thanks Yash for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work for my setup. Only the laptop's battery `battery_BAT0`, the line power `line_power_AC`, and the mysterious `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice` device show up in the output.

Answer (score 28):

You don't see Battery Level in the list of GATT characteristics since Bluez v5.48 because this specific GATT characteristic was moved into [DBUS `org.bluez.Battery1` interface](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/battery-api.txt).

From the command line:

1. Connect to your target BLE device with `bluetoothctl`
2. And then request DBUS by running: `dbus-send --print-reply=literal --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_<mac_address_of_your_ble_peripheral> org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.bluez.Battery1" string:"Percentage"`

In my case with my BLE peripheral with the following MAC address `C3:41:A6:C8:93:42`:

```bash
$ dbus-send --print-reply=literal --system --dest=org.bluez \
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C3_41_A6_C8_93_42 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
    string:"org.bluez.Battery1" string:"Percentage"
   variant       byte 94
```

Note: You could potentially scan and connect to your device using Bluez DBUS API.

Comment: When following these instructions, I get this error `$ dbus-send --print-reply=literal --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_09_EF_A6_24_70 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.bluez.Battery1" string:"Percentage"
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'org.bluez.Battery1'`

Comment: Which 'bluez' version are you using?

Comment: @OlivierM, I'm using bluez 5.50 on archlinux

Comment: I have just tried 5.50 from the Bluez sources and it also work for me. Are you sure your device expose battery service? Can you run this command: `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_09_EF_A6_24_70 org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect`

Comment: Hi @OlivierM, I'm sorry I missed your last comment. I tried that command and gave me a long output that's kind of hard to parse. You can see it at https://gist.github.com/rhz/b904398b1526db1c2fe208a61d09e24d. There's no mention of a Battery property for the device. What does that mean?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem as @Ricardo, I'm using bluez 5.50-6 on Archlinux and I also don't have the `org.bluez.Battery1` interface; my introspect output is https://gist.github.com/Terseus/d78e6ca711cef914e52bffd757d40c5b

Comment: @Terseus, same as Ricardo. Your device use A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile), your batterz information might be accessible through this profile. See my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment99304776_49078659

Comment: @OlivierM Can please also give the dbus command for `bluez < 5.48` ?

Comment: I got rid of the `No such interface 'org.bluez.Battery1'` issue, after enabling experimental features on the bluetooth daemon. Got that fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125875/589216. I'm currently on bluetoothd version 5.64 on Ubuntu 22.04.3. It now even shows up in KDE's "battery-panel".

Answer (score 22):

This is such a great question, ahead of development and tools that are available at the moment.

**The short answer** (in October 2018)

> you have to write it yourself! It won't be a one liner in the terminal. I am going to write this for myself in Python, but C has a little more documentation, so if you are skilled with C go for it.

**The long answer**, but it's more a recommended starting point:

1. Tony D: https://youtu.be/5fQR2PHMDWE?t=4644 managed to use `bluetoothctl` to read attributes and send data to a bluetooth device. Definitely check the video information, you will find great links and references: https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt
2. Szymon Janc: https://youtu.be/VMDyebKT5c4 developer and contributer to the LINUX Bluetooth Stack
3. **Definitely** check out how this question is answered on Mobile devices. For Android it's the BAS (Battery Service): https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106073/displaying-bluetooth-gadgets-battery-status-on-the-phone

   [image: On Android 8.0.1]

Comment: I checked the first video and the guy uses `list-attributes` in `bluetoothctl`, which doesn't show anything in my case. That's why I'm thinking maybe there's a non-GATT way to check the battery status? I checked the other links too, except the talk by Szymon Janc which is a bit too long. Please let me know if you're successful in writing a program that reads the battery level of a BLE device.

Comment: Don't forget to use `sudo` when running `bluetoothctl`. But yeah, there really isn't a comfortable way to do this in Linux, today. That is also the motivation for this python project: https://github.com/peplin/pygatt#motivation 
I am not going to go further with my research,  of this subject due to lack of time. Use the above git project and example code, if you decide to continue this Path of solving this issue. https://github.com/peplin/pygatt#example-use 

I will probably only be able to help again, next year. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @VeRo for the help! I didn't know I was supposed to run `bluetoothctl` as root (using `sudo`). I tried that and still nothing shows up when I do `list-attributes` after connecting to the device. Not sure what should be done to get the attribute listed there or what can be done if the device doesn't list any gatt attributes. Cheers!

Comment: Update by (Kernel Developer)

`something has to register the battery with the power-supply
subsystem using power_supply_register (or the variant prefixed
with devm_). For the BT HID devices that happens in
drivers/hid/hid-input.c and is based on the HID protocol. Other
BT devices do not use HID protocol and need their own handler.
AFAIK for other device types the highlevel protocols are implemented
in userspace/bluez. That would require something like uinput for
power-supply, so that bluez can feed battery information back into
the kernel. AFAIK nobody is currently working on that.`

Answer (score 8):

One possible way (although hacky) is to grep inside the journal:

```
journalctl -b --user-unit pulseaudio -g "Battery Level" -o cat
```

(`-b` to only show information in the current boot. Clearly information in the previous boots are irrelevant)

On my machine this outputs for example

```
Battery Level: 70%
Battery Level: 70%
Battery Level: 70%
Battery Level: 70%
Battery Level: 70%
Battery Level: 60%
Battery Level: 60%
```

Pick the last line (which can be done by appending `|tail -n 1`).

This solution does not distinguish whether the Bluetooth device is currently connected, or which one is in case there are more than one.

---

Alternative includes running `bluetoothctl disconnect`, then use the script in the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59709851/5267751 to get the battery level, then run `bluetoothctl connect` again. This is usually not acceptable if you're currently connected, but it works.

---

Another alternative, if it works for you, is to use an experimental feature of bluez package. Refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/1420501/996767.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 20+, it shows the battery under the devices tab in the power panel

[image]

Comment: That's great news! Hopefully this feature appears soon in KDE as well.

Comment: Can't see that in Ubuntu 22.04, experimental=true has already been set. am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to get battery level via pulseaudio logs with some [hack](https://github.com/sre/pulseaudio/commit/d66b66d20e9bc73e6d0ca89283cf2b5675304b00).
My bluetooth headset uses proprietary Apple HFP AT commands, HFP/A2DP protocols are handled by pulseaudio directly. It seems the only way to get those values is through pulse.

Comment: Thanks Vasily and sorry for the long delay. Do you know if there is a way to send those AT commands from the command line (using `dbus-send` for instance) to obtain the battery level?

Comment: You can build pulseaudio yourself and apply mentioned patch. You can modify it: for example, replace pa_log_notice with output to some pipe in /tmp and have app that monitors that pipe. I chose this way. Works for me. That code is triggered only once, when device is paired. You can place it on volume change functions. I think there is a way to add dbus listener to specific command in pulseaudio, so that it will trigger PA to send those AT commands, but this is too compilcated for me.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I would rather not maintain a fork of pulseaudio.

Answer (score 4):

By default Bluez 'hides' the Battery Service UUID. This is because there is a 'battery plugin' loaded at startup of bluetoothd.

If you don't want the battery plugin to be activated and make the Battery Service UUID visible again to bluetoothctl or any other application, then change the startup command for bluetoothd to be like this: 'bluetoothd -P battery'. That will make sure the battery plugin is not loaded. On a Raspberry Pi the bluetooth.service is located in /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service so you need to make the change in that file.

Comment: Please do not modify packaged unit files (those under `/lib` or `/usr/lib`) directly. Systemd offers the `systemctl edit` interface for modifying units in a way that does not cause issues with package managers.

Answer (score 2):

In the bluez version you are using the Gatt attributes may be experimental.If so you need to enable the experimental characteristics by running the bluetoothd deamon by -E keyword
Like "/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E"
this worked for me.

Comment: The bluetoothd deamon is run by systemd when you do "systemctl start bluetooth" right? How can I tell systemd to use the -E parameter? I have bluez version 5.48

Comment: While executing the 'systemctl start bluetooth' command you are invoking the bluetooth.service ,search for this service in you home directory.Inside the service you can add the -E parameter to the line invoking the bluetoothd.It comes as part of the bluez package.The line would look something like this "ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd" add -E parameter to the end of it "ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E".

Comment: After adding this keyword when you connect your device using bluetoothctl app it will list the supported services by your bluetooth device.from that you can select-attribute for the "Battery-Level" service and use read command to get the value.There are also ways to get the battery level directly by usinf dbus-send a utilit used to send dbus commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I changed the line as you suggested, then did "systemctl deamon-reload" then "systemctl restart bluetooth" (both as root). Then started bluetoothctl, connected the device, "menu gatt", "list-attributes [dev]"... but still nothing. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: To which device are you trying to connect

Comment: I'm connecting to some headphones. Seems like gatttool has been deprecated in bluez: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617. According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Troubleshooting, gatttool has been replaced by btgatt-client. However, I wasn't able to make it work. I tried "btgatt-client -v -d [device address taken from bluetoothctl]" and got "Connecting to device... Failed to connect: Operation not supported".

Comment: If possible could you post the code inside your bluetooth.service.Which bluez versio  are you using.

Comment: And also could you post the info of your device from the bluetoothctl app.

Comment: Its May be because your speaker don't advertise the battery level through the Gatt services.you can try following command through dbus-send "dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/ org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.bluez.Battery1 string:Percentage"

Comment: try like this "dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.bluez.Battery1 string:Percentage" there was an extra backslash in the earlier comment

Comment: `dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_09_EF_A6_24_70 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.bluez.Battery1 string:Percentage` gives me `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'org.bluez.Battery1'`

Comment: bluetooth.service: `[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service`

Comment: in bluetoothctl I do `info E9:09:EF:A6:24:70` and I get `Device E9:09:EF:A6:24:70 (public)
        Name: MPOW-059
        Alias: MPOW-059
        Class: 0x00240404
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no` ...

Comment: ... `UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)`

Comment: I have bluez version 5.48

Comment: I am not able to find BatteryService in your UUID info,it may be advertising the battery level in some other way.What i understood is that Gatt characteristics are mainly vendor specific.Is the app you are using to fetch the battery level of your device provided by the manufacture of the headphone or is it a generic one?Could you please provide the Manufacture data or more details about your headphone?

Comment: The app I'm using to fetch the battery level on my android phone? It's just android itself that tells me the battery level of the bluetooth device on the notification bar. Where can I find more information about the headphones? What I pasted here is all I get from bluetoothctl. Is there any other tool on linux to get information from bluetooth devices?

Comment: I am not able to see the UUID for the battery service in the list of UUIDs you have given here are you sure that your device is advertising the battery level through gatt characteristics even in androif app its internally using ths genric UUID to fetch the battery level which is not present in your advertised UUIDs by your speaker

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I be sure?

Comment: Search for the device mac in your '/' mostprobably it will be inside /var directory and inside the device directory there is an attributes file in that you can check for the UUIDs supported by your device.Check if has the GATT UUID for battery service.

Comment: `sudo ls /var/lib/bluetooth/40:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/E9:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/` shows there's only the file `info` in it but no file `attributes`.

Comment: could you try these steps,connect to the device(after pairing),tyoe info in bluetoothctl,copy the list of UUIDs you are getting and paste it here.or use the command list-attributes and paste the output here.X180F this is the uuid for battery service please do check whether you can find anything like this in your list of attributes.

Comment: The command `list-attributes` returns nothing. The command `info E9:09:EF:A6:24:70` gives me the following list of UUIDs: `00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, `0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, `0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, `0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, `0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, and `0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`. None of them have the substring `X180F`. I can't find anything like that in either the list of attributes or the list of UUIDs in `info`.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is specific to headphones/headsets)

I'd been using the Python program from clst's answer for some time and although it worked, it required me to connect, then disconnect and run it again. If I understand the problem correctly, that happens because
only one program can open a socket to talk to the bluetooth device, so it ends up fighting with PulseAudio over it.

I've recently found out about [hsphfpd](https://github.com/pali/hsphfpd-prototype).

> hsphfpd is specification with some prototype implementation used for connecting
> Bluetooth devices with HSP and HFP profiles on Linux operating system.

Basically, since only one program can communicate with the headset at once and it wouldn't make sense to implement battery level reporting in an audio server, nor implement audio in a power management software, it moves that functionality to an external daemon. That way, PulseAudio and whatever can both use the headset at the same time. There is a [version of PulseAudio](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/288) patched to use hsphfpd. Even though these are both still prototypes, they seem to work very well.

hsphfpd reports battery status (and other stuff) through DBus, so to get it from the command line, you can just do

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.hsphfpd --print-reply /org/hsphfpd/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/hsp_hs org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.hsphfpd.Endpoint string:BatteryLevel
```

or even call it from a program.

Both of these are available in the AUR, if you use Arch Linux.

Comment: When running `dbus-send --system --dest=org.hsphfpd --print-reply /org/hsphfpd/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/hsp_hs org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.hsphfpd.Endpoint string:BatteryLevel` I get `method return time=1606703580.141858 sender=:1.3546 -> destination=:1.3550 serial=44 reply_serial=2
   variant       int16 -1`

Comment: @Ricardo You could try `hfp_hf` or `hfp_ag` instead of `hsp_hs`. If that doesn't work, open `pavucontrol` and switch to either HFP or HSP (even if they say unavailable), then try again. After this, you can switch back to whatever profile you were using, or else you'll be stuck with very low quality audio. If that still doesn't work, try using `QDBusViewer` to inspect the `org.hsphfpd` service and find any alternate paths you may be able to use. Let me know if you manage to make it work.

Comment: When I use `hfp_hf` I get `variant       int16 40`. I guess that 40 means 40% battery left. Not sure how to verify that as the new setup makes the program in the accepted answer not able to connect to the device. Maybe I'll just wait and see if the number goes down with use. Thanks for the help!

When using `qdbus --system org.hsphfpd` I see that both `hfp_hf` and `hsp_hs` are available for this device.

Comment: @Ricardo That's correct. As far as I know, hsphfpd uses a similar method from the script from the accepted answer, so the value should be the same. Also, you could also connect to the `PropertiesChanged` signal to be notified when the battery level changes. Note that it only updates if the `Connected` property is `true`.

Comment: Cool. By charging the headphones the number increased to 60. I think it might only be sensitive to 10% increases and decreases. Thanks a lot! This answer is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check the battery for my JBL Headset was to issue the command below: (Command issued in Ubuntu 22.04)

```bash
pactl link sink
```

This will show the following, in my case:

```
Sink #2
    State: RUNNING
    Name: bluez_sink.<MAC>.a2dp_sink
    Description: JBL TUNE710BT
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 24
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 32660 /  50% / -18,15 dB,   front-right: 32660 /  50% / -18,15 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: bluez_sink.<MAC>.a2dp_sink.monitor
    Latency: 56606 usec, configured 42414 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
        bluetooth.codec = "sbc"
        device.description = "JBL TUNE710BT"
        device.string = "<MAC>"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_<MAC>"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "JBL TUNE710BT"
        bluetooth.battery = "100%"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, available)
    Active Port: headset-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

As it' possible to see, exists a Property called `bluetooth.battery` that shows the battery percentage.

---

Following the procedure stated in https://askubuntu.com/a/1420501/82644 I could show the battery percentage under Settings > Power and also using `upower --dump`

Step by Step

1. Add `Experimental = True` after `[General]` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. Restart the bluetooth service `systemctl restart bluetooth`
3. Connect (or Reconnect) you bluetooth device
4. Check battery percentage at Settings > Power

```bash
sudo cp /etc/bluetooth/main.conf /etc/bluetooth/main.bkp
sed '/General]/a Experimental = True' /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | sudo tee /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

But a WARNING!
After doing that, I can't use this python script https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level or `pactl list sinks` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Am posting this today, because today I have tested this method **successfully**.
I received a tip from [`@Mr.Newbie`](https://github.com/search?q=mr+newbie&type=Users)
A python solution: [Bluetooth Headset Battery Level by `@TheWeirdDev`](https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install extension for gnome and "Bluetooth battery indicator" Work perfect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

As said by @OlivierM above, the UUID is filtered by bluetoothd. You could undo that and export the UUID just as any other service characteristics by removing the following from the `export_service()` function in `src/gatt-client.c`

```c
if (gatt_db_service_get_claimed(attr))
     return;
```