# Read battery status bluetooth headset linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluez

I use Bluetooth headset that use Bluetooth version 4.1. When I connect with android it shows the battery status. But with Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) I cannot get battery status. I tried with `bluetoothctl`, looking file in `/sys/class/power_supply` as in other questions, But they didn't help me.

[askubuntu.com/questions/53880/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-battery-percentage-of-apple-wireless-peripherals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53880/is-there-any-way-to-check-the-battery-percentage-of-apple-wireless-peripherals)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux)

My bluetooth device don't use GATT profile. It uses A2DP sink for streaming audio.

I looked Bluez documentation. They all said is do with GATT profile and get the attributes.

Is there a way to read battery status even with pragmatically in Linux properly? How does android device get the battery status? Is it a weakness of Linux Bluetooth stack?

Comment: It is likely that your device is using a custom attribute for the battery level. Can you try the following and post the output:- Run "bluetoothctl", then "menu gatt", then "list attributes [dev]" and replace [dev] with the headset's Bluetooth Address.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed When I type `menu gatt` and the `list-attributes [device-mac]` It prints nothing.

Comment: @mimix2 Maybe have a look to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008142/6267288. It is not clear if the Bluez DBUS org.bluez.Battery1 is specific to GATT or not. Looking quickly at the code, it looks to be GATT dependent but I might be wrong.

Comment: @LakinduAkash You need to `connect [device-mac]` before `menu gatt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [this pull request by Dmitry Sharshakov](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/merge_requests/504), PipeWire has support for reporting battery status (with devices that use Apple HFP AT commands). It uses bluez's Battery Provider API, which is still experimental and is only available if `bluetoothd` is started with the `-E` flag.

On Arch Linux, it should be enough to run

```sh
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service /etc/systemd/system/
sed -i -r 's/ExecStart=.+/& -E/' /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

And the headset battery level should appear. To get the battery level programatically, you can then use UPower's DBus API.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 too. You can use command line upower -d or Unity GUI

Answer (score 3):

### Just Enable Experimental Mode for bluetooth (bluez) and its done.

#### Steps to Enable Experimental Mode:

> **NOTE**
>
> Remember to edit the file in sudo or doas or root mode.

- Open `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` in a text editor.
- Go to Line where it is written `# Experimental = false`
- Change the line to `Experimental = true` and also remember to remove the `#` symbol for the line to make it a command instead of a comment.
- Then Run this command

  ```bash
  sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
  ```

And You are done. Enjoy :)

Comment: If you do not have the line `# Experimental = false` in the file, just add it under the `General` section.